# Combine two hashes in ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to combine the following two hashes using ansible.

```
secret:
  env1:
    password: p1

public:
  env1:
    username: u1
```

The result should be

```
combined_hash:
  env1:
    username: u1
    password: p1
```

I can't work out how to use the combine filter with with_dict or with_together (if that's the right approach at all) in the same task.

It appears this might work (as per http://toroid.org/ansible-combine)

```
{'a':{'x':1}}|combine({'a':{'y':2}}, recursive=True)
    → {'a':{'x':1, 'y':2}}
```

But I'm at loss as to how to convert this hardcoded example to using {item.0: item.1} style.

Comment: Do you think if it will be helpful? https://github.com/leapfrogonline/ansible-merge-vars#merging-dicts

Comment: It does not support the key value depth I require (and if it does, apologies I'm too noob to figure out how).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the `combine` filter.

```
$ cat test.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    secret:
      env1:
        password: p1
    public:
      env1:
        username: u1
  tasks:
    - name: test combine hashs
      set_fact:
        combined_hash: "{{ secret | combine(public, recursive=True) }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ combined_hash }}"
```

> ```
> TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => {
>     "msg": {
>         "env1": {
>             "password": "p1", 
>             "username": "u1"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

You can get more info here: [Combine filter on Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)

Comment: I've tried about a million things.. Having revisited the doc, I can see what I missed. Thanks